# "I wondered what it was" or "I wondered what it were"

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

It's a question about the subjunctive mood.
Let's say you found out the name of a new object. Which construction would be grammatically correct/more frequently spoken?

"I wondered what it was" or "I wondered what it were"?

My doubt is: if you didn't know it in the past, then are we in the subjunctive mood?

Comment: Which do you think is better and why? Then we can help clarify your doubts.

Comment: I think the most common is "I wondered what it was". My doubt is: if you didn't know it in the past, then are we in the subjunctive mood?

Comment: We don't use the subjunctive here.  This is just a simple statement about the past: It **was** a strange-looking fish; I wondered what it **was**.

Comment: Did you search both phrases in Google, Google Books, etc. and see which one yields more results? Did you [do any research](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?